# TensorFlow apply_gradients remotely

Tags: gradient, tensorflow

I'm trying to split up the minimize function over two machines. On one machine, I'm calling "compute_gradients", on another I call "apply_gradients" with gradients that were sent over the network. The issue is that calling apply_gradients(...).run(feed_dict) doesn't seem to work no matter what I do. I've tried inserting placeholders in place of the tensor gradients for apply_gradients,

```
  variables = [W_conv1, b_conv1, W_conv2, b_conv2, W_fc1, b_fc1, W_fc2, b_fc2]
  loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv))
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4)
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
  compute_gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, variables)

  placeholder_gradients = []
  for grad_var in compute_gradients:
     placeholder_gradients.append((tf.placeholder('float', shape=grad_var[1].get_shape()) ,grad_var[1]))
  apply_gradients = optimizer.apply_gradients(placeholder_gradients)
```

then later when I receive the gradients I call

```
  feed_dict = {}
  for i, grad_var in enumerate(compute_gradients):
        feed_dict[placeholder_gradients[i][0]] = tf.convert_to_tensor(gradients[i])
  apply_gradients.run(feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

However, when I do this, I get

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

This is only the latest thing I've tried, I've also tried the same solution without placeholders, as well as waiting to create the apply_gradients operation until I receive the gradients, which results in non-matching graph errors.

Any help on which direction I should go with this?

Comment: note that the use of placeholder (to stand in for the gradient tensors in `apply_gradients`) is unnecessary, since you can feed a numpy value for any variable (tensors). you can just use the original gradient tensor returned by `compute_gradients`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that each `gradients[i]` is a NumPy array that you've fetched using some out-of-band mechanism, the fix is simply to remove the [`tf.convert_to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#convert_to_tensor) invocation when building `feed_dict`:

```
feed_dict = {}
for i, grad_var in enumerate(compute_gradients):
    feed_dict[placeholder_gradients[i][0]] = gradients[i]
apply_gradients.run(feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Each value in a [`feed_dict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) should be a NumPy array (or some other object that is trivially convertible to a NumPy array). In particular, a `tf.Tensor` is not a valid value for a `feed_dict`.

Comment: OMG that was it, thank you so much, been working on this for a week.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I had a hard time finding info on how feed_dict works, other than the code itself. Maybe I could post an issue for it to spit out a helpful error message.

Comment: The main docs are in the documentation for [Session.run()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session), which describe what may be passed in a `feed_dict`. I think we've also [recently improved](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4c3b060b9b063a247172c939e0e1314577b581e3/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L370) the exception that is raised in this case, but that might not be in the current release just yet!

Comment: In tensorflow 1.8.0, compute_op returns a tuple for a single variable. The first is a control dependency and the second is the actual gradients. Hence make sure to change ```feed_dict[placeholder_gradients[i][0]] = gradients[i][1]``` to avoid shape mismatch errors